# Construct ANOVA like table for sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I want to make ANOVA table for sklearn as it is returned by statsmodel library. I can compute residual sum of square but unable to understand how [iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5]  sum of square are computed. Could anyone explain it?

My other question does it make sense to use StandardScaler() of the variables in a linear regression case, or should I only use it in the classification task.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from scipy import stats

dv = [0.75, 1.00, 1.00, 0.75, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00, 1.00, 0.75, 0.50]
iv1 = [0.75, 1.00, 1.00, 0.75, 0.75, 1.00, 0.50, 0.50, 0.75, 0.25]
iv2 = [0.882, 0.867, 0.900, 0.333, 0.875, 0.500, 0.882, 0.875, 0.778, 0.867]
iv3 = [1.000, 0.067, 1.000, 0.933, 0.875, 0.500, 0.588, 0.875, 1.000, 0.467]
iv4 = [0.889, 1.000, 0.905, 0.938, 0.833, 0.882, 0.444, 0.588, 0.895, 0.812]
iv5 = [ 18, 16, 21, 16, 18, 17, 18, 17, 19, 16]
d = {'iv1': iv1, 'iv2': iv2,'iv3': iv3, 'iv4': iv4,'iv5': iv5}
d2 = {'dv':dv,'iv1': iv1, 'iv2': iv2,'iv3': iv3, 'iv4': iv4,'iv5': iv5}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x_train=df.to_numpy()
y_train=np.array(dv)

linear_model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
#pipe=Pipeline([  ('StandardScaler',StandardScaler()), ('regression',linear_model)])
pipe=Pipeline([  ('regression',linear_model)])
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

LR= pipe.named_steps['regression']
beta=LR.coef_
intercept=LR.intercept_
print('beta',beta)
print('intercept',intercept)

yhat=pipe.predict(x_train)
residual_ss=np.sum((y_train-yhat)**2) 

cancer=smf.ols('dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3 + iv4 + iv5', data=d2).fit()
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(cancer, typ=1)
print('ANOVA',anova_table) 

ANOVA            df    sum_sq   mean_sq         F    PR(>F)
iv1       1.0  0.033989  0.033989  0.776151  0.428075
iv2       1.0  0.022435  0.022435  0.512307  0.513703
iv3       1.0  0.003048  0.003048  0.069596  0.804959
iv4       1.0  0.115143  0.115143  2.629357  0.180222
iv5       1.0  0.000220  0.000220  0.005023  0.946900
Residual  4.0  0.175166  0.043791       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Those values you see for individual predictors are sequential sums of squares (that you can read about here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/6/6.3). I am saying this in a friendly, trying-to-help way: don't waste your time trying to reproduce the ANOVA table yourself, as it will be like recreating a good chunk of statsmodels source code.

Comment: Thanks friend for the link. As it pointed out in the example that order of the predictor variable is important to find out the SSR then it seems having no significance meaning what I was expecting for the predictor variable. Thanks for the suggestion.